# Regexp help for amounts

Tags: python, regex

I have struggled with an regexp expression in Python but can't get to it. I would be very grateful for help. The problem is that I need to sort out amounts where the amounts could have space as thousand separator. A short example could be (have lot more letters and words in te text) -

`se556399 2 705,48 25,00 676,37 0,15 3 382,00`

where

```
2705,45
25,00
676,37
0,15
3382,00
```

are amounts

One example to solution (that dose not work are) -

```
\d+\s?\d+,\d\d
```

A more complicated text -

```
pullman s13 1 125,94190828pågår19091537,0j94,00 126,00 1,00bdagpu100 160,00 16,00 10,00dammsugarpåse pullman s13pu101 350,00 350,00 1,00stoftavskiljare filter s13 13,09544000slang 4-5m dammsug 38mm 10,01190828pågår19091537,0j1,00 1,10 1,00bdag 13,09544001munstycke dammsug 38mm 10,01190828pågår19091537,0j1,00 1,10 1,00bdag900 200,00 200,00 1,00transport56 0,01 0,01 1,00kört av curtonr 247608 objekt 191049 anm tel 070-309 47 87 erref johan karlsson vårref fredrik b depå nacka 5,08814strålkastare 72+108w lågenergi 150,25190909pågår19091537,0j40,00 35,00 1,00bdag 5,08658strålkastare 72+108w lågenergi 150,25190909pågår19091537,0j40,00 35,00 1,00bdag 5,08652strålkastare 72+108w lågenergi 150,25190909pågår19091537,0j40,00 35,00 1,00bdag 5,05260882strålkastare stativ 1-2m 41,67190909pågår19091537,0j0,00 4,41 3,00bdag900 100,00 100,00 1,00transport06 0,01 0,01 1,00kört av håkanförsäkring 5% dag 90,26nyhet hyr online. där kan du som kund se pågående ordrar, söka skriva ut. godkänd för f-skatt momsvat nr se559999 2 705,48 2 705,48 25,00 676,37 0,15 3 382,00
```

Comment: This is very difficult to parse and follow. If spaces are the thousands separator, what is the number "48 25"?

Comment: Please improve your question's title so that it describes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this :

```
\d{1,3}(?:\s\d{3})*,\d{2}
```

This regex parses numerals where digits are grouped by 3 in groups separated by spaces, with a comma as floating point separator and always two decimal digits.

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/6MGKrh/2).

Comment: Great. This is the closet to a solution I have seen. If I don't manage to find a solution I will go for that. The text are so complicated so I dont think I will find a perfect solution. I have updated the question with a more complex version of the text.

Comment: The question remains unaltered

Comment: Now it should be updated

Comment: @user2856066 is [this](https://regex101.com/r/6MGKrh/3) what you're looking for? If not please tell me what problem you're having with my solution, it's not obvious as is

Comment: It's almost perfect. Some minor things. It dose not match 90,26 and the first match also includes 00 witch instead should belongs 94,00.

Comment: @user the regex I posted in my answer did match those, maybe it would be easier to work with? What did this one do wrong?

Comment: For example, in first line it matches 00 126,00 instead of two matches like 94,00 and 126,00

Comment: The one from the comment yes, the one from the answer no. I'm asking you what's wrong with the regex from the answer

Comment: Seems that i misunderstood one thing. I first thought 900 100,00 should not be a match - and probably not but as I wrote the question you have correctly match the whole amount (sorry if it sounds messy). Anyway - thanks for a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d\s)?\d+,\d\d
```

works for your example. Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/)